# Run binary with highest priority

Tags: linux, unix, nice

I am running one binary with highest priority like

```
nice -n -20 binary
```

Now I want to run same binary such that it runs with high priority without **nice -n 20 binary** like

```
 ./binary // runs with high priority same as nice -n -20 binary with any setting
```

Are there any configurations which says kernel to start process with higher priority when I start binary with ./binary,I don't wont to start binary with **nice -n -20 binary** every time

So how to do it give your suggestion

Answer (score 3, accepted):

you can create alias for it

```
alias binary='nice -n -20 binary'
```

after that if you execute binary then it will start with higher priority

Answer (score 2):

Create a script that contains your `nice` command, and run that instead.

e.g.

```
echo  nice -n -20 binary > binary2
chmod +x binary2
```

And then to run it, just do this:

```
./binary2
```

Answer (score 0):

I believe you want something like this,

```
sudo nice -n -20 ./binary
```

From `info coreutils 'nice invocation'`

> Only a privileged user may run a process with lower niceness:

Comment: I'm running this command using root user and its work well but my question is are there any configuration which says kernel  to start process with higher priority when I start binary with ./binary,

Comment: what happened now that I need to start binary with nice -n -20 ./binary every time to assign higher priority to it

Comment: Ok fine but is there any other way?